# Is having no reviews normal? If not, how do I fix this?

Tags: support, review-queues

I unlocked the review queues privilege on SO yesterday, but after clicking it, found nothing to review. After waiting another day, nothing has changed. I see a red circle *as if* there is something to review:

[image]

but when clicked, see nothing: [image]

Upon clicking all queues, I see that there are indeed things to review:

[image]

I've heard that this could be due to a buffering issue, but am not sure how to fix it. Can someone please help?

Comment: That's weird. You're not review banned either (not that that's a shock when you've just been granted access and haven't done any reviews yet.). Do you have an ad blocker installed, that might be a bit too aggressive on the review queue HTML?

Comment: Yes, I use Ublock Origin, but after disabling it I still see the same thing.

Comment: @RyanFu - What browser are you using?  Only those versions supported by Chromium, Apple, Google, and Microsoft are supported by Stack Exchange.

Comment: Chrome, on the latest version

Comment: I ran into this issue with the suggested queue ([10k+ only](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413596/suggested-edit-queue-not-loading-any-new-tasks) (question demonstrating similar issue, no review tasks appearing, however I was getting a "An error occurred when loading the review item. Please try again." error in addition to that)). My issue resolved itself automatically after a combination of 10 minutes and several refreshes.

Comment: Could you try it again? I just tried accessing the review queues and looks like they're now working again.

Comment: Yeah, it works now!